# How do I hide the cmd windows when rotating logs?

Tags: cmd, window, uwamp

I added this command to httpd_uwamp.conf :

```
#LOG ROTATION
TransferLog "|C:/UwAmp/bin/apache/bin/rotatelogs.exe C:/UwAmp/bin/apache/logs/backup/access-%Y_%m_%d.log 5M"
```

It works fine, but cmd window is always visible while Apache is on.

Does anyone know how to hide this cmd window ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me too with my access logs. I couldn't figure out a solid solution but for now I hide it through the command line using this tool found here: 
https://steve.fi/Software/windowhide/

I've used it on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012

Credits go to Steve Kemp .. steve@steve.org.ku

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting... You might want to check on what user profile your server is starting and make sure it's running as a service.

My rotatelogs windows finally cleared away when I ran my server applications as a service..

Under the Task Manager the username is now SYSTEM and no longer my user name.

With this modification, an "Interactive Services Detection" window would popup presenting the option to view the prompts from a self-contained screen.

[image: "Interactive Services Detection"]

I also modified the httpd.conf and moved my "CustomLog" and "ErrorLog" lines to the  directives as they were outside, though I don't think it'll affect the outcome.